# CSS file won't affect output?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So, I'm doing this portfolio tutorial, and the code is basically correct, but for me the css part has no affect on the output. the code is correct, but i'm not sure why...
My repo link: [Porfolio react app](https://github.com/ddcc3388/Portfolio)

Here is my html code

```
      <h3 className="font-bold">Take a look of our projects</h3>
      <hr />

      <div className="row">

          {projectsdata.map(project => {
              return <div className="col-md-4">
                      <div className="position-relative project">
                        <img src={project.image} alt='' />
                      
                      </div>
                </div>
          })}

    </div>
```

And Here is my Css code:

```
[.projects-intro .primary-button{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.project{
    padding: 20px ;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.486);

}
.project img{
    height: 220px !important; 
    width:100% !important;
}]
```

It's meant to look like this.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKHIQ.png)Image

But mine shows up like this:[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zY7M.jpg)Image

Comment: Why is CSS code in brackets? `[]`

Comment: Also you probably didn't import `bootstrap` or whatever the `col-md-4` comes from.

Comment: It might help if you could put up a working snippet. As the query is basically ‘is the CSS being used’ we need to see how you are including both the bootstrap and your own CSS.

Comment: You can make use of width and height properties in css for divs

Comment: [link](https://github.com/ddcc3388/Portfolio)
Here is my repo for this react app. Someone please take a look!!

Answer (score 0):

try to set the width, then set the height to auto

```
.project img{
    height: auto; 
    width: 220px;
}
```

don't use the important only if you want to override a 3rd party library

> however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets -- [Mozilla Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception)

Comment: are your images vector?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/ddcc3388/Portfolio)
Here is my repo for this react app. Someone please take a look!!